# Are heap snapshot identifiers guaranteed to be monotonically increasing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, heap-dump

I'm using heap snapshots to debug a potential memory issue. As the documentation indicates objects are shown in this format:

```
ObjectConstructorName@NumericIdentifier
```

Where [NumericIdentifier is](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling):

> This is an object ID. Displaying an object's address makes no sense, as objects are moved during garbage collections. Those object IDs are real IDs — that means, they persist among multiple snapshots taken. This allows precise comparison between heap states. Maintaining those IDs adds an overhead to GC cycles, but it is only initiated after the first heap snapshot was taken — no overhead if heap profiles aren't used.

I'm wondering if the identifiers are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing? That is given:

```
ObjectConstructorName@10001
ObjectConstructorName@10002
```

Can I rely on the first object to be older (was allocated before) than the second one?

If yes - how strong is the guarantee? (Does it hold between constructor names for instance?)

Comment: Looking at [the HeapSnapshotGenerator](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/bb0975878f3994eee09e95b5dbb3336105889cc0/src/profiler/heap-snapshot-generator.cc) code - I tend to believe the answer is "no". It does look like [it increases by 2](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/bb0975878f3994eee09e95b5dbb3336105889cc0/src/profiler/heap-snapshot-generator.h#L249) but I don't see a guarantee that [iterating the heap](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/bb0975878f3994eee09e95b5dbb3336105889cc0/src/profiler/heap-snapshot-generator.cc#L427) is ordered

Comment: It's best to ask a developer who works on that file at their IRC channel or https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! I've already asked two V8 engineers who work on that content in a pre-existing private chat as part of my capacity as a developer in Node.js - but it is not reasonable to expect them to "drop everything" and answer and it might take them days or they might be disinterested in answering entirely (which is totally reasonable and acceptable). I figure there are a lot of smart engineers on Stack Overflow and some probably know the answer :)

Comment: HeapObjectsMap::GenerateId seems related, which means the id is hash-based, not ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following up. After talking to several V8 engineers:

- They were not sure if the guarantee currently holds.
- They have/had no plans to make such a guarantee and it's not someone one can rely on.

Comment: when we compare snapshot A and snapshot B, does the chrome dev tool perform set A-B operation and share details for objects reachable in snapshot-A and not reachable in snapshot-B ? or all objects reachable in particular snapshot ?